# Why is this considered a "romantic" poem?

Tags: writing, poetry, rhymes

In Willam Blake's poem, what makes it a romantic poem?

> I wandered through each chartered street,
>   Near where the chartered Thames does flow,
>   A mark in every face I meet,
>   Marks of weakness, marks of woe.
>
> In every cry of every man,
>   In every infant's cry of fear,
>   In every voice, in every ban,
>   The mind-forged manacles I hear:
>
> How the chimney-sweeper's cry
>   Every blackening church appals,
>   And the hapless soldier's sigh
>   Runs in blood down palace-walls.
>
> But most, through midnight streets I hear
>   How the youthful harlot's curse
>   Blasts the new-born infant's tear,
>   And blights with plagues the marriage-hearse.

Can romantic poems have rhymes?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that William Blake is one of the archetypal [Romantic Poets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romantic_poetry). That Wikipedia article puts Blake first in a list of the six most well-known Romantic Poets, ahead of Wordsworth, Coleridge, Byron, Shelley, and Keats.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question...for the now defunct Literature.SE.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be better asked in Writers SE.

It is Romantic because it is about 'real-life' and written in allegedly 'natural' language. This style was pioneered by Wordsworth in 'Lyrical Ballads' and explained in [the preface to that volume](http://www.bartleby.com/39/36.html), where he said he would "adopt the natural language of men" and "chuse incidents and situations from common life". His poem ["Michael"](http://rpo.library.utoronto.ca/poems/michael-pastoral-poem) in the same volume (1800 edition) illustrates the style well.

This is a contrast to earlier styles when poetry was written in very flowery language, and the subject was often mythical situations. Milton's ["At a Solemn Music"](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/at-a-solemn-music/) for example.

There is no reason why Romantic poetry should not rhyme. That is a choice made by the poet.

Answer (score 3):

***Romantic*** is a period in the history of literature beginning in the latter eighteenth century, and to which Blake belongs. There's a list in the related [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romantic_poetry).

The poem is romantic precisely because it is a product of this period. The name has nothing to do with romantic *love* (although there is romantic-period poetry which is romantic in that sense); and the rhyming-scheme is the author's choice.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Andrew Leach's answer: "Romantic" has nothing to do with romantic love. For example, consider Mary Shelley's *Frankenstein*, which is a product of the Romantic era. Someone even once wrote, "*Frankenstein* is the quintessence of romanticism." ([Ref.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081102234615AAh5XSu))

Answer (score 1):

Much romantic poetry rhymes, although Blake is perhaps not best thought of as a Romantic poet. That description is ususally applied to the likes of Wordsworth, Coleridge, Keats and Shelley.